# how to read file using path in ruby by function IO.readlines("path")[0]

Tags: ruby

i want to read first line of file by using following function in ruby

```
IO.readlines("path")[0]
```

But file is not in current directory, so i use path there

```
puts IO.readlines("Home/Documents/vikas/SHIF.doc")
```

but it is giving error as

```
a1.rb:1:in `readlines': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - Home/Documents/vikas/SHIF.doc (Errno::ENOENT)
    from a1.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The given path does not start by a "/" or a drive specification (if you're in Windows), so it is a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

You can also open a file and read only the first line instead of the entire file

```
File.open("Home/Documents/vikas/SHIF.doc").readline
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.expand_path`:

```
puts IO.readlines(File.expand_path("Home/Documents/vikas/SHIF.doc", __FILE__))
```

Note however that it will create path relatively to a file directory, not to a root directory.

If you are using rails, you could use:

```
puts IO.readlines(Rails.root.join 'Home', 'Documents', 'vikas', 'SHIF.doc')
```